# Form validation using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to make a function for text input validation and its not working.

JavaScript:

```
function validateText(id)
    {
    
    var x=document.forms["myForm"][id].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  var text = id+"Text";
  document.getElementById(text).style.visibility ="visible";

  }else {
     var text = id+"Text";
  document.getElementById(text).style.visibility="hidden";
      
      
      }
    }
```

Html:

```
<label for="familyName">Family name</label>
<input type="text" id="familyName" id="familyName" onBlur="validateText(familyName)">
<p id="familyNameText">Test 123</p>
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Is `onBlur="validateText(familyName)"`supposed to be `onBlur="validateText('familyName')"`?

Comment: Yes it is good eye :) thanks a lot.

Comment: The JS console is your friend.

Comment: I'd also recommend you use a library for validation. It would make your life a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevmo mentioned a library, here is a quick and dirty example using [jquery](http://jquery.com/). Once you have the basics of javascript mastered look into jQuery, it will make your life a lot easier.

**HTML** not the absence on any calls to javascript functions and our required fields have the `required` class

```
<form id="formToValidate">
    <label for="familyName">Family name</label>
    <input type="text" id="familyName" id="familyName" class="required">
    <p class="requiredText">Family Name Required</p>
    <label for="familyName">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" id="firstName" class="required">
    <p class="requiredText">First Name required</p>
    <label for="familyName">Dogs' name</label>
    <input type="text" id="dogName" id="dogName">
</form>
```

**CSS** Just some basics

```
.requiredText {
    display:none;
    color:#F00;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
.required {
    border-color:#F33;
}

input {
    width:60%;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

**Javascript**
I've used the following from jquery:

- [Document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Value](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [Blur Event Handler](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)
- [Next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [SlideDown/Up](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () { /* Execute when DOM is loaded */
  /*Assign blur event handler to fields with required class */
  /*I have used the id of the form (#formToValidate) to scope the selctor. 
    Not required but a good practice*/
    $("#formToValidate .required").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") { /*Check the value of the item being blured"*/
            $(this).next(".requiredText").slideDown('fast'); /* Slide down the nearest alert text sibling*/
        } else {
            $(this).next(".requiredText").slideUp('fast'); /* Slide up the nearest alert text sibling*/
        }
    });
  });
  ```

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Mb29/